# Angular nested reactive forms are not touched

Tags: angular, forms, components, reactive

**I try to implement nested reactive forms in angular.**

But when I call `markAllAsTouched()` and `updateValueAndValidity()` in the submit function the nested inputs are not touched and therefore the error message isn't displayed.

I tried a hack to touch the inputs when the outer form is touched with this code in the `statusChanges` subscription

```
if (!this.control.touched && this.parentForm.touched) {
  this.control.markAsTouched();
  this.control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

But this leads to every form been touched when I enter text in one of them and therefore displaying the error message to soon.

*What am I doing wrong? Are reactive forms in angular meant to be used this way?*
I want to have a single button that touches and updates every nested form element in the outer form.

I provided a repo on github (https://github.com/to-cl/testform) where I recreated the error.

---

In `appComponent` there is a `testForm` that includes several custom input fields.

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
  <app-myinput [parentForm]="testForm" label="Comment" type="text" formControlName="comment"></app-myinput>
  <app-myinput [parentForm]="testForm" label="Name" type="text" formControlName="name"></app-myinput>
  <app-myinput [parentForm]="testForm" label="Email" type="text" formControlName="email"></app-myinput>
  <app-myinput [parentForm]="testForm" label="Password" type="text" formControlName="password"></app-myinput>
  <button style="margin: 1em;" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'form-test';

  testForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      comment: [],
      name: [],
      email: [],
      password: [],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.testForm.valid)
    this.testForm.markAllAsTouched();
    this.testForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

---

The custom input fields are components on their own:

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" style="padding: 1em;">
    <label style="padding-right: 1em">{{label}}</label>
    <input id="value" formControlName="value" type="text" [required]="required">
    <small style="color: rgb(209, 67, 67)" *ngIf="control.touched && control.hasError('required')">
        required
    </small>
</form>
```

Component:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, forwardRef, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myinput',
  templateUrl: './myinput.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myinput.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyinputComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyinputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class MyinputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  form: FormGroup;

  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  @Input()
  label: string = '';

  @Input()
  formControlName = '';

  @Input()
  parentForm!: FormGroup;

  @Input()
  required: boolean = true;

  get control() {
    return this.form.controls['value'];
  }

  get value(): any {
    return this.form.value;
  }

  set value(value: any) {
    this.control.setValue(value)
    this.onChange(value);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {

  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      value: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(
      // any time the inner form changes update the parent of any change
      this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        this.onChange(value.value);
        this.onTouched();

        this.manipulateValidators();
      })
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.addStatusChangeSubscription();
    this.addValueChangeSubscription();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
  }

  addStatusChangeSubscription() {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.parentForm.statusChanges.subscribe(() => {
        if (this.parentForm.disabled && !this.form.disabled) {
          this.form.disable();
        }

        if (this.parentForm.enabled && !this.form.enabled) {
          this.form.enable();
        }

        if (!this.control.touched && this.parentForm.touched) {
          this.control.markAsTouched();
          this.control.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
      })
    );
  }

  addValueChangeSubscription() {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.parentForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        if (this.value.value !== value[this.formControlName]) {
          this.form.patchValue({ value: value[this.formControlName] }, { emitEvent: false })
        }
      })
    );
  }

  validate(_: FormControl) {
    let formInvalid: any = {};
    formInvalid[this.formControlName] = { valid: false };

    return this.form.valid ? null : formInvalid;
  }

  onChange: any = () => {
    /* Left blank intentionally */
  };
  onTouched: any = () => {
    /* Left blank intentionally */
  };

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  manipulateValidators(): void {
    if (this.required && !this.form.controls['value'].hasValidator(Validators.required)) {
      this.form.controls['value'].addValidators(Validators.required);
    }
    if (!this.required && this.form.controls['value'].hasValidator(Validators.required)) {
      this.form.controls['value'].removeValidators(Validators.required);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: The github code doesn't seem to be related to that, did you push everything?

Comment: Yes I forgot to push everything. I updated it now.

Comment: I don't see the issue, I can see, that after pressing the button the word required pops up after every input field. Isn't the requested behavior?

Comment: But when you edit any of the inputs all the others show the required message too.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, will mark all controls as dirty.

```
export function markAsDirty(control: FormGroup | AbstractControl) {
  control.markAsDirty();
  if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(control.controls)) {
      markAsDirty(control.controls[key]);
    }
  }
  if (control instanceof FormArray) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(control.controls)) {
      markAsDirty(control.controls[key]);
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: I think that is exactly the behaviour that is not desired. This marks all controls dirty, but only the current form and the parent form should be touched.